# How to disable automatic indenting when typing ':' in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When i write a classes constructor typing `:` to start the initialization list of a C++ constructor Visual Studio indents the line when it is right after a `namespace` directive. Also when i type `::` (scope resolution) Visual Studio indents the line, which i found very annoying since the indentation was correct in the first place and i always have to undo Visual Studio's indentation.

Example:

This is what i haved typed:

```
namespace XY {

MyClass::MyClass()
```

now i type `<space>:`, and VS indents:

```
namespace XY {

     MyClass::MyClass() :
```

which is not what i, uh, intended.

This behaviour is - strictly speaking - correct, according to the rules of the "Smart Indenting" option of MSVC. But in this context it is not what I want.

Is there a way to turn off smart indenting in this context? I suppose that it is a quite common style **not** to indent namespace blocks.

Comment: 'Do you know how to disable this "feature"?' Use vi!

Comment: @Shynthriir:  Oh, how very stone age of you. :)

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3894937-option-to-stop-indenting-namespaces-in-c-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is behaviour is the preceding `namespace` directive:

```
namespace XY {

MyClass::MyClass()
```

So MSVC wants to indent the constructor definition.

Mea culpa.

Comment: I'd hardly say it's your fault. You've found the cause, but the main question is still unanswered. How do you *disable* that indentation?

Comment: @John Dibling: Thanks for the hints, I restated my question

Answer (score 2):

This is for VS9:  Go to Tools>Options>Text Editor>C/C++>Tabs.  Under **Indenting** "Smart" will probably be selected.  Select "None" and you are bingo.